# Power BI - Slicer stopping "show items with no data" from working

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm frustrated that neither I could solve what seems to be a simple issue or find the solution online.

Say I have this dataset:

[image]

Then I go to the report page and set up a slicer with the "Name" and a matrix with the "Object" and "Price", as below:

[image]

So far so good.

Then, I know Jane doesn't have a car and a bicycle but I want to show all the itens, including these ones Jane doesn't have, at the matrix. So I click in "Show items with no data".

[image]

And then, for my surprise, nothing happens...the itens Jane doen't have are still not showing at the matrix...

What's the catch here and workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-show-items-no-data)  to better understand how "Show items with no data" actually works. Your data model is too simple and doesn't meet the criteria for the feature to make a difference.

> The Show items with no data feature doesn't have any effect in the
> following circumstances:
>
> - There's no measure added to the visual, and the grouping columns come
>   from the same table.
> - Groups are unrelated. Power BI doesn't run
>   queries for visuals that have unrelated groups.
> - The measure is
>   unrelated to any of the groups. In this case, the measure will never
>   be blank for only some group combinations.
> - There's a user-defined
>   measure filter that excludes blank measures. For example: SalesAmount >0

Your model doesn't have any measures, there are really no combinations with no data, all values are from the same table, and you are applying a filter that limits the data. Take a look at the examples in the article to see scenarios that get the feature to show.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way around, create a measure/column and use it instead of the field.

Something like :

```
var a = Calculate(Sum(price))
return
If(Isblank(a), 0, a)
```

Or simplifying even more:

```
If(Isblank(Calculate(sum(price)),0,Calculate(sum(price))
```